# Square root of a continuous function

Tags: real-analysis, cv.complex-variables

Is it square root of a real $\alpha-$Holder continuous function $f$ defined on $[0,1]$ a $\alpha/2$ Holder continuous, provided $\sqrt{f(x)}$ it exists and is continuous, i.e. whether $|f(x)-f(y)|\le C|x-y|^\alpha$ implies that $|\sqrt{f(x)}-\sqrt{f(y)}|\le C'|x-y|^{\alpha/2}$.

Comment: It seems this is a simple question, C'=2\sqrt{C}

Answer (score 2):

$$
\begin{aligned}
\left|\sqrt{f(x)}-\sqrt{f(y)}\right|&=\frac{\bigl|f(x)-f(y)\bigr|}{\sqrt{f(x)}+\sqrt{f(y)}} \\ 
&\le\min\left(\sqrt{f(x)}+\sqrt{f(y)},\frac{C|x-y|^\alpha}{\sqrt{f(x)}+\sqrt{f(y)}}\right) \\
&\le\sqrt C\,|x-y|^{\alpha/2},
\end{aligned}
$$
as desired.
(The inequality here follows because $\min(u,c/u)\le\sqrt c$ for all positive real $c$ and $u$.)